# How do I attach a ref to an event in fullcalendar-react?

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, react-ref

I'm wanting to use a combination of [fullcalendar-react](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-react) and [react-dnd](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/use-drag) to be able to drag calendar events elsewhere.

React-dnd is simple enough - it provides a couple of hooks that generate refs, that you attach the 'draggable' or 'droppable' element target:

```
import { useDrag } from 'react-dnd'

function DraggableComponent(props) {
  const [collectedProps, drag] = useDrag({
    item: { 
        id: "foo", 
        type: "bar"
    },
  })
  return <div ref={drag}>...</div>
}
```

Using fullcalendar-react then - I want to make the rendered calendar event a 'draggable' target.

However, from what I can see, the fullcalendar-react component doesn't actually compose of React sub-components - it's essentially [one component that is doing DOM manipulating directly via the original library](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-react/blob/master/src/FullCalendar.tsx). We do have access to the event DOM elements directly via the [`eventRender` callback.](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender)

Is there a way to make a ref refer to a DOM element directly?